# Starting activity intent in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to use the starting another activity intent in AndEngine as I use it in my original Android apps, it doesn't work.

**Logcat**:

```
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onResumeGame(BaseGameActivity.java:222)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$4.run(BaseGameActivity.java:373)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
02-19 18:32:49.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**code** :

```
                startActivity(new Intent(StartingActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
```

Note that sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Trying to achieve the same thing since last week i have seen this appearing randomly! I am also noticing that the activity is destroyed and recreated for no apparent reason. One reason might be the configuration change, but i have fixed my activity orientation to sensorlandscape. See if it does anything to you

Comment: run on UI thread.It will work

Comment: How to run it on UI thread? I am running it now in onTouch of a sprite

Comment: post more code. there is nothing that can be null in the code posted so far.

Comment: This is my only intent code right now, do you want any specific codes?

Comment: activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ }); place your code in this one and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public synchronized void onResumeGame() {
    if (this.mEngine != null)
        super.onResumeGame();
}
```

solved it by using this code, referrence https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/issues/7

Answer (score 1):

1. your problem is mEngine is null, in onResumeGame method.
2. finish(); is not needed.
3. Do you extend from SimpleBaseGameActivity directly?
4. Do you use emulator?